# Making product card responsive

Tags: css, responsive

I needed to make a div and the content inside responsive using percentages rather than pixels.

I found that using percentages for the size of the div worked best, I then had the choice of whether to use `EM` or `responsive queries` for the font size; I found that the quires worked best for this.

```css
section {
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  padding: 50px;
}

.container {
  width: 30%;
  height: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

.background {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.text h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #000;
  font-family: 'open sans';
}

.text p {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000;
  font-family: 'open sans';
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class=" container">
    <span class="background "></span>
    <span class="gradient_bottom "></span>
    <div class="overlay ">
      <div class="text ">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eget dolor auctor, tempor nibh.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

In the code you can see that I used a percentage for the container but stated pixels for the section, this is so the container knows to be 80% of the sections stated width.

I then used media queries for the points of the text I needed it to decrease. You can see an example below.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.text h1 {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using pixel measurements, the displayed size is dependent upon the resolution of the screen viewing the content, rather than the actual size of the display. In order to make your content responsive to screen sizes, you should either use percentages or other css measurements which are dependent upon the amount of space available, rather than the amount of pixels.

A great place to get started learning how to make this content responsive is at this link: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp

If you are just asking how to include a percentage measurement rather than a pixel measurement, you would use `width: 50%;` as opposed to `width: 100px;` etc.

Also, when using responsive web design it is important to set the viewport of document. You can do this with this snippet:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Read more about viewport here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

You can also use media queries in CSS to define certain CSS rules for certain screen sizes. Here is an example of a css rule which sets all elements with the class `someclass` to a width of `50%` when the screen size is under `500px` wide.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
 .someclass {
    width: 50%;
 }
}
```

Media queries are very powerful, and really help you optimize your site for the best look across a range of screen resolutions and sizes.

Definitely read the guide on responsive web design here, as there is much more to it than just using percentages here and there. 
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you want the cards to have a minimum width and a maximum with which also like "stretch" between you can use a percentage width and min- & max-width. Lets say you want to have the card to be minimum 200px and maximum 300px then just write it. the rest is magic from the percentage value youve given the card. Hope this answers your question.